# Volterra Operator Gives Zero?

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the operator $K(\varphi)(t)=\int_{s=-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(t-s)\varphi(s)ds$. If we will look at $K(e^{int})$ we will get zeros $ \forall n\in N$, thus it means that we got the zero operator? (because this is a basis to $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$)

Comment: Who says you get $0$ for all $n$?

Comment: Maybe I made a terrible mistake, but isn't the integral zero?
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+-pi+to+pi+of+sin(t-s)*e%5E(i*n*t)

Comment: The integration variable is $s$, you need to input "sin(t-s)*e^(ins)". And you should probably tell Alpha that $n$ is an integer. And that $s$ is the variable of integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n = \pm 1$ you don't get zero: instead,
$$ K(e^{is}) = i\pi e^{it} $$
and
$$ K(e^{-is}) = -i\pi e^{-it}, $$
so these are eigenfunctions with eigenvalues $\pm i\pi$. These do span the image of $K$, however, as is slighly clearer if you use the angle addition formula and use sine and cosine, or use the exponential formula for the sine.